# Ho do I stop SLAVA YURTHEV from sending messages to our back end Magento administration page?

Tags: magento2, messages, administration

This is something that in 15 years of Magento use we have never encountered. 
A developer, (whose extension we PURCHASED), will not stop sending marketing messages to the administration page of our Magento site.

He has found some way to break in to allow his commercial marketing messages and refuses to stop. Additionally, there is no way to delete them as they show up as a banner on the page rather than a message in the messages area.

Needless to say, there is no "unsubscribe" button either. Essentially, he is spamming our Magento 2.3 Administration site and we want it to stop.

Any advice?
[image]

Comment: You should provide the link to the plugin. or upload the plugin code here so we can take a look.

Comment: Thank you.  The extension is here: https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/Slider-M2

Comment: I don't see anytning in there that would do that. Can you include the html code of that block?

Comment: Perhaps you installed a different version of their plugin:  I just installed it and it did nothing of that sort

Comment: We have had his slider installed for 4 years, they do not appear when you install it- it appears periodically (in the last year only) as a banner in admin. So far, it has been to promote the server services that he received a commission on but if it is working then it will no doubt be used for other commercial purposes- in a PRIVATE area.  If you leave his slider on your Magento site then you will eventually receive  banners, (Not messages),.  My point is that these marketing messages are "breaking in" to my admin page without permission or a way to unsubscribe- hence, they are spam.